# How to send multiple sms messages as response to Twilio's single request

Tags: asp.net-web-api, twilio

I have to send multiple SMS messages as response to Twilio's single request 
in Asp.Net WebApi (C#). How do we achieve that? Each message should come as a separate sms on the phone.

Is there a way to do that?

Edit:

If I have something like this :

```
 var response = new TwilioResponse();
 if (smsBody == "MESSAGE")
 {
    response.Sms("Message One");
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,   response.Element);
 }
```

can I give another

```
 response.sms("Message One");
 response.sms("Message Two")? 
 return .....
```

Will this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Are you asking how to send multiple messages back in response to an incoming message?  If thats the case, you can just include multiple `<Sms>` verbs in your response:

```
<Response>
    <Sms>Message One</Sms>
    <Sms>Message Two</Sms>
</Response>
```

This tells Twilio to send two messages back to the number that send the inbound message.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes. So will it be for the same response but two Sms messages? So would each one count for the 160 characters. i.e. message one = 160 and Message Two = 160?

Comment: I updated my initial post. Can you please review if we can do something like that as well?

Comment: ok. Great. So can each of those message be 160 characters? i.e. Message 1 as 160 characters and message 2 as 160 characters. Is that right?

Comment: Yup...each can be 160.

Comment: One more question. If I have a list of messages in a List Collection. Can I simply call the response.Sms to add my messages in the foreach loop or will it overwrite?

Comment: Every time you call the Sms() method on the TwilioResponse object it will add a new <Sms> tag to the response.